# How to populate Elementor form field in popup with spoiler title

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup, elementor

I have spoiler I want to send title of the item I click on it, the content has button that opens the popup with the form.
I can get the title with jQuery, but I can't populate the input with the value.
this code is getting the value and populate the input

```
var job_title = "";

jQuery('.careers_toggle h2.elementor-tab-title .elementor-toggle-title').click(function(){
        title = jQuery(this).text();  
        title = jQuery.trim(title);
        job_title = title;
        
        jQuery('#job_title').val(job_title);
        
    });
jQuery('#form-field-first_name').on( "focus", function(){
            jQuery('#job_title').val(job_title);
    });
```

job_title is the ID of the input, but none of the options is setting the value.
How do I set the value? I did it with Contact form 7 and other popup plugin, but I don't want to add more plugins